# Add column for each unique value in given row

Tags: r, csv, dplyr

I am trying to change the format of my current data set to one that has 1 user per row, and which splits all the unique values (dynamic number of values) in the Color and Food columns into their own columns with Yes and No. Each user has a unique ID.

```
Current format: 
ID | Name  | Color  | Food 
1  | John  | Blue   | Pizza
1  | John  | Red    | Pizza
1  | John  | Yellow | Pizza
1  | John  | Blue   | Ice Cream
1  | John  | Red    | Ice Cream
1  | John  | Yellow | Ice Cream
2  | Kelly | Blue   | Pizza
2  | Kelly | Red    | Pizza


Desired format: 
ID | Name  | Color_Blue | Color_Red | Color_Yellow | Food_Pizza | Food_Ice Cream |
1  | John  | Yes        | Yes       | Yes          | Yes        | Yes            |
2  | Kelly | Yes        | Yes       | No           | Yes        | No             |
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(ID:Name)) %>%
  unite("col", c(name, value)) %>%
  distinct(ID, Name, col) %>%
  mutate(val = "Yes") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = "val", values_fill = "No")

# A tibble: 2 x 7
  ID    Name  Color_Blue Food_Pizza Color_Red Color_Yellow `Food_Ice Cream`
  <chr> <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     <chr>        <chr>           
1 1     John  Yes        Yes        Yes       Yes          Yes             
2 2     Kelly Yes        Yes        Yes       No           No
```

If you want a base R equivalent, here's one using the same steps. (Can someone please help me figure out how to remove the rownames and the "val." that gets appended to the final column names?)

```
df2 <- reshape(df, 
        direction = "long", 
        varying = c("Color", "Food"),
        v.names = "Value",
        timevar = "col_name",
        times = c("Color", "Food"))
df2$col = paste(df2$col_name, df2$Value, sep = "_")

df3 <- unique(df2[c("ID", "Name", "col")])
df3$val = "Yes"

df4 <- reshape(df3,
               direction = "wide",
               idvar = c("ID", "Name"),
               timevar = "col")
df4[is.na(df4)] <- "No"

> df4
        ID  Name val.Color_Blue val.Color_Red val.Color_Yellow val.Food_Pizza val.Food_Ice Cream
1.Color  1  John            Yes           Yes              Yes            Yes                Yes
7.Color  2 Kelly            Yes           Yes               No            Yes                 No
```

sample data

```
df <- tribble(~ID , ~Name  , ~Color  , ~Food,
"1"  , "John",  "Blue",    "Pizza",
"1"  , "John" , "Red",    "Pizza",
"1"  , "John",  "Yellow",  "Pizza",
"1"  , "John" , "Blue",   "Ice Cream",
"1"  , "John",  "Red",    "Ice Cream",
"1"  , "John" , "Yellow", "Ice Cream",
"2"  , "Kelly", "Blue",    "Pizza",
"2"  , "Kelly", "Red",    "Pizza")
```

Answer (score 1):

Cleaned up base R script:

```
# Data to import: df => data.frame
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Name = c("John", 
"John", "John", "John", "John", "John", "Kelly", "Kelly"), Color = c("Blue", 
"Red", "Yellow", "Blue", "Red", "Yellow", "Blue", "Red"), Food = c("Pizza", 
"Pizza", "Pizza", "Ice Cream", "Ice Cream", "Ice Cream", "Pizza", 
"Pizza")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

# Function to extract the column names of data.frame 
# not contained in a character vector: 
# resolve_other_vec_names => function
resolve_other_vec_names <- function(df, vec_names){
  # Explicitly define returned object: character vector => env
  return(
    colnames(df)[!(
      colnames(df) %in% vec_names
      )
    ]
  )
}

# Create a formula to aggregate a data.frame by:
# resolve_agg_formula => function()
resolve_agg_formula <- function(keep_vecs){
  # Formula object to aggregate data.frame by:
  # res => formula object
  res <- as.formula(
    paste(
      ".", 
      paste0(
        keep_vecs,
        collapse = "+"
      ),
      sep = "~"
    )
  )
  # Explicitly define returned object: formula => env
  return(res)
}

# Function required to aggregate vector by:
# agg_func => function
agg_func <- function(df, agg_formula){
  # Function to agg by: .agg_vec_by => function
  .agg_vec_by <- function(x){
    ifelse(
      any(x),
      "Yes",
      "No"
    )
  }
  
  # Aggregate data.frame: res => data.frame 
  res <- aggregate(
    agg_formula, 
    df,
    FUN = .agg_vec_by
  )
  
  # Explicitly define the returned object:
  # data.frame => env
  return(res)
}

# Function to spread a data.frame's vector, 
# from unique row-values to column vectors:
# spread_func => function()
spread_func <- function(df, vec_name){
  # Extract the unique values of a given vector:
  # y => vector
  y <- unique(df[,vec_name])
  
  # Determine if a row contains a given value in y:
  # row_contains_value_df => boolean data.frame
  row_contains_value_df <- data.frame(
    outer(
      df[,vec_name], 
      y,
      `==`
    ),
    row.names = NULL
  )
  
  # Create the data.frame vector names: 
  # df_vec_names => character vector
  df_vec_names <- paste(
    vec_name,
    y,
    sep = "_"
  )
  
  # Rename the data.frame vectors: res => data.frame
  res <- setNames(
    row_contains_value_df,
    df_vec_names
  )
  
  # Explicitly define the returned object: data.frame => env
  return(res)
}

# Function to combine list of data.frames into df: 
# df_list_2_df => function
df_list_2_df <- function(df_list, cmb_func = c(rbind, cbind)){
  # Resolve the desired combination function: 
  # cmb_func_resolved => character scalar
  cmb_func_resolved <- match.fun(cmb_func)
  # Combine list of data.frames into a data.frame 
  # using a given combination function: res => data.frame
  res <- data.frame(
    do.call(
      cmb_func_resolved,
      df_list
    ),
    row.names = NULL
  )
  # Explicitly define the returned object: 
  # data.frame => Env
  return(res)
}

# Define the main function: main => function
main <- function(){
  # Vectors to spread values to columns: 
  # spread_vecs => character vector
  spread_vecs <- c("Color", "Food")
  
  # Vectors to keep as columns: keep_vecs => character vector
  keep_vecs <- resolve_other_vec_names(df, spread_vecs)
  
  # Formula to aggregate the data.frame by: 
  # agg_formula => formula object
  agg_formula <- resolve_agg_formula(keep_vecs)
  
  # Resolve if person/id has observed value: 
  # res => data.frame
  res <- agg_func(
    cbind(
      df[,keep_vecs],
      df_list_2_df(
        lapply(
          spread_vecs,
          function(x){
            spread_func(df, x)
          }
        ),
        cbind
      )
    ),
    agg_formula
  )
  
  # Print data.frame to console: data.frame => stdout(console)
  res
  
}

# Execute main if called:
if (sys.nframe() == 0){
  # Execute the main function: data.frame => stdout(console)
  main()
}
```

Comment: I don't want to rag on your code, but this is why people invented tidyverse.

Comment: @user438383 ok, if you ever work in an environment where they don't allow package installation and you want to use R, you'll need to learn Base R. One other thing: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/380026/391730

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to come off as attacking. And sure, I understand both those points. It's not about the number of lines, but how totally unintuitive the highly nested style that base-r forces you to write is. I could stare at that for a long time and have no clue what it's meant to be doing. I would there seems to be a thing here where people try and just do everything in one enormous nested statement rather than splitting it into multiple parts, which must hard for newcomers to R to learn.

Comment: @user438383 no worries. I understand the arguments for the tidyverse, particularly relating to the benefits of monadic code (i.e. is more readable, doesn't as many intermediate result objects etc.), and even use the tidyverse myself. There are other issues relating to requiring installation from CRAN (which is often a breach of security policies), splitting the language separate languages, deprecation of functions limiting the lifespan of code, and also performance (which is generally worse than base / data.table -- not applicable in this case). So I generally offer base R solutions.

Comment: @user438383 I think it's probably most important to note that the reason you would stare at the code for a long time and not understand what it's doing is because you don't understand Base R the same way you understand the tidyverse (which sort of demonstrates my point about language splitting). Having taught R to undergraduates, I would agree they generally find the tidyverse much easier to learn.

Comment: @user438383 at any rate, took your advice and cleaned up the script and provided some notes explaining whats going on.

Comment: @user438383 for interests sake this answer is very good too: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/380032/391730 I would argue TCO of tidyverse (which generally only solves trivial problems) is higher due to changes in security that would have to be applied, risk of deprecation (which is high), performance generally being poorer than base/data.table alternatives (which could result in actual costs when deployed), and splitting of language isolating older R users from being able to understand the code base.